# Dynamically changes in android installed app those changes reach to live users installed app

Tags: android, android-update-app

I actually want's to reach app changes in to user installed app.How this can possible.

1- My app is live on play store.

2- There are 30,000 of live users.

There is a bug in app and i resolved that bug now i don't want to upload new version of app on play store there is only small change so i don not update that version to play store now i don't want  all users will update for small change updated build.

What i need to do for this if there is any tool to user device installed app that bug fixed which is i resolved.

I am not using Web-services for that change so data is not depend on web server.
Is there any tool or any other way to reach users installed device that change for that all these changes reflect to user installed app??.

without any user authentication by playstore.
or is there any way to reach these changes to user device.

Comment: No. Update the app on the Play Store.

Comment: I dont want to upload my apk or versioning of apk, without upload new version i want those changes i done those reach to user device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, like it or not, but there's no mechanism you can use to replace installed app or hot swap it portions on user's  device other than reinstall.

In future release you could add ie push messages telling user to download the update from your server (but that would require enabled sideloading to have it installed).

Comment: No not i don't expect this from top repudiated stack user this  answer . I make RND or many ways i search i found only one that is Google Strict mode publish build with updated version , in market there is not any tool like this to update build installed in device of user.

Comment: This same knowledge i has , i got this question from one of source and i reply same to him but that guy say no this is possible at that time i feel may be this can possible from any of the tool may be so i posted this question on stackoverflow .

Answer (score -1):

There is only single answer all over the stack or E- bloggers as well google Developers answers.

We can upload our build at Google play store at Strict mode , Strict mode make without user authentication or permissions update build and that build reach to user installed device .

In case of (User must have Internet connection or when user get connected by internet or WiFi same time app automatically update without any User Intersection or this process user can not view that particular app is updated or not) if user know this particular app previous version like "1.1" and now "1.2" then only user can understand app is updated in my device without user permission.

Google added this in Play store publisher account this feature for Developers some of the developers know very well but some not.

All changes Reach to user installed app in this case user not required to make app update from Play Store.